Why did maven compile failed on CircleCI? Could not collect dependencies for project
It is quire big project,on local Ubuntu machine everything works fine. Then on the circleCI server first steps are ok(spin out environment,chekout code,clean m2).
although clean m2 shows

Go offline step
mvn clean install -Dskiptests .ciclci/m2/settings.xml 

works fine.
But
mvn clean compile -o -s .ciclci/m2/settings.xml

gives error
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project pizd-common-config: Could not collect dependencies for project com.**********.apps:pizd-common-config:jar:6.0.0-SNAPSHOT
[ERROR] Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.commons:commons-collections4:jar:4.4
[ERROR]         Caused by: The following artifacts could not be resolved: org.apache:apache:pom:21 (present, but unavailable): Cannot access AnapicRepository (****************************************************) in offline mode and the artifact org.apache:apache:pom:21 has not been downloaded from it before.
[ERROR] Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:jar:4.4.16
enter code here

where does maven looks for repository it can not find?
Why? where to search for root cause?
